# google map api v3 in app

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

I am creating an app that uses google map. i inserted the map api key inside the html page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api /js?key=AIzaSyDcvUkjiKRkJ2zV8cYElZy55JLZDjiL9g8&sensor=false"></script>
```

i keep getting error saying " Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not valid Google API key, or it is not authorized for google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site ". i just followed whatever they had mentioned in here

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key
```

i don't have any problem when run this code in my html. Only problem is that some of the map page don't render out properly. Which version is better to use V2 or V3 ?

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```

i am kinda confused. Can someone help me out what i doing wrong or what do i need to do. Since my app is totally based google map. Thanks

Comment: There is a pace between /api and /js in your line: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api /js?key=AIzaSyDcvUkjiKRkJ2zV8cYElZy55JLZDjiL9g8&sensor=false"></script>
This is the only script you need to insert in your page. It will load the lastest version (v3) of the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possibilities for you:

Either you use this line in your code `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=CHANGE_YOUR_KEY_HERE&sensor=false"></script>` and you generate a new key for you application: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key
(on the screenshot you can see the link "Generate new key...")

Or you use this line  without bothering with having a key. (for example: http://jsfiddle.net/LZmQ2/)